# Groovy-Issue: recalling a closure inside of a vbox again, when a spinner's stateChanged fires an action

Tags: swing, groovy, action, spinner, vbox

If you take the numPanels as a fixed value of e.g. 20, it's really a nice and groovy swinging.

But I try since two days to add more or less panels with a groovy.swing.Spinner dynamically  (my program will be used to connect to different databases and exchange values from different db-tables). I tried with binding, revalidating, repainting - but I can't bring the closure to take the new value from the spinner...

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import javax.swing.WindowConstants as WC
import javax.swing.JOptionPane
import javax.swing.JScrollPane
import javax.swing.BoxLayout as BXL
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel

int numPanels = 2

swing = new SwingBuilder()

def setPanelAmount = swing.action(name:'Amount of Panels in vbox-element',  closure: this.&setPanelAmount )

frame = swing.frame(title:'test', pack:true, visible:true, defaultCloseOperation:WC.HIDE_ON_CLOSE) {
panel(id:'mainPanel'){
scrollPane( verticalScrollBarPolicy:JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS ) {
  vbox {
    (1..numPanels).each { num ->
      def panelID = "panel$num"
      def pane = panel( alignmentX:0f, id:panelID, background:java.awt.Color.GREEN ) {
        label('description') 
        textField( id: "description$num", text:panelID, columns: 70 )
        button( id: "buttonpanel$num", text:panelID, actionPerformed:{
          swing."$panelID".background = java.awt.Color.RED
        } )
      }
    }
  }
}

boxLayout(axis: BXL.Y_AXIS)
panel(id:'secondPanel' , alignmentX: 0f){                       
 hbox(){
 label 'Change amount of panels:'
 hstrut(10)
  spinner(id: 'numPanelSpinner', stateChanged: this.&setPanelAmount, model: new SpinnerNumberModel(2, 2, 10, 1))
  hstrut(50)
  button('Quit', actionPerformed:{
    frame.visible = false
  })
  }
}
}       
}
frame.size = [ frame.width, 600 ]

def setPanelAmount(event) {
    numPanels = swing.numPanelSpinner.getValue()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be combined with the following code - but unfortunately, it's not working with an included closure - at least as far as I know now...

```
import groovy.swing.*
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.*
import java.awt.BorderLayout as BL

new SwingBuilder().edt {
  frame(defaultCloseOperation: JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, visible: true, size: [600,500]) {
   panel(id:'main') {
    panel {   
      button(name:'x', action: action(name:'add', closure:{p.add(label('new')); p.revalidate()}))
      button(action: action(name:'remove', closure:{p.removeAll();p.revalidate();scroll.repaint()}))
}

panel() {
  scrollPane(id:'scroll',preferredSize: [200,200], constraints: context.CENTER) {
    panel(id:'p') {
      checkBoxList(listData: (1..20).collect([]){"Option $it"} as Object[])
    }
  }
}
  }
 } 
}
```

BTW.: do you like to improve in programming groovy, too?
I would be glad to start a git-based "engineering" with my program.
This program will compare a user given amount of lists with articles coming from one or more databases or excel-files, save them and every result in PostgreSQL or MSSQL.
Every list may have zero, one or more articles listed identified by their article-numbers, with varying amounts in each entity.
And the user can - guided by a GUI - decide in which order to add or subtract the entities from another. The other (zero to infinite) attributes beside of article-number and amount will be carried through the lists.
Not too complicated but for a first project...